# Using Oracle combine 2 coloumns into one from junction table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've taken over an Oracle DB but almost everything is in one table. Which is a complete nightmare. So I've created a few junction tables to try and trim down the detail table. However I stumped on how to convert 2 fields into one. For example below.

Here is a sample of the detail table. Currently the account and task id in 2 separate columns.

Ive included an acc_task_id. This I need to populate with the acc_Task_id from the junction table. Where the account and task_id match. Once complete. 
I will drop the account and task id from the detail table.

- oracle 11g
- 3.5 million rows

[image]

[image]

How this will how it would end up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE detail_tbl dt
   SET dt.acc_task_id = ( SELECT at.acc_task_id FROM acc_task_jun_tbl at
                           WHERE NVL(at.acc_id, -1) = NVL(dt.acc_id, -1)
                             AND at.task_id = dt.task_id )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM FROM acc_task_jun_tbl at
                 WHERE NVL(at.acc_id, -1) = NVL(dt.acc_id, -1)
                   AND at.task_id = dt.task_id );
```

Note that I use `NVL(acc_id, -1)` (assuming that `-1` is not a valid value for that column) as `NULL = NULL` doesn't work.